# Determining enrichment of p-values

Tags: p-value, genetics

I have two diseases (called A and B for simplicity) with epidemiological evidence that are related, and I want to show that there is some genetic evidence for it. Through genome-wide association studies (GWAS) a number of genetic differences (called SNPs) have been found independently for each of the two diseases.

200 of these SNPs have been found to be associated with disease B. To see if there was any genetic relation, I looked up the p-values of association for these SNPs in disease A. I've plotted a histogram of these p-values and there is a large peak at the lower levels.

[image: histogram of pvalues]

I think this is sufficient, especially since I'm not making any strong assertions. However, my boss wants some level of significance (biologists' obsession with p-values!). I've come up with two possibilities:

1) Under $\alpha = 0.05$, you would expect 10 SNPs of the 200 to be below 0.05. Therefore, I can take the count that are observed to be < 0.05, and do a binomial or Poisson test.

2) Randomly sample 200 SNPs from all the association p-values, perform a test to compare the samples (Kolmogorov–Smirnov?). Permute.

Are either of these sensible? Or am I over-complication things, and there's a much simpler way of doing this comparison?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't quite answer your question, but I think what you're looking to do is compute the level and significance of genome-wide pleiotropy between two traits. I would use bivariate REML as implemented in [GCTA](http://cnsgenomics.com/software/gcta/reml_bivar.html). I realize that this isn't exactly what you asked, but I believe it's the answer that would give you the best results.

If you would like an example of how it's used, take a quick look over my paper [here](http://www.nature.com/ejhg/journal/vaop/ncurrent/full/ejhg2015162a.html). I'm the first author, so if you have any questions please ask. See in particular the **Genetic correlations between obesity and CAD** section. I would also read [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22843982) paper if you are interested in using this method.

I hope someone else can provide an additional solution, but this is the best that I know.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did previously use GCTA and REML, but the results were unsatisfactory. The main issue was that my datasets are enriched for families with the disease. Still, it may be worth revisiting.

Comment: Ah, my apologies @steiny. Sorry to tell you something that you already knew. In that case, I quite like your second idea. I've definitely heard of people doing this before with similar aims in mind. Working with familial data, I've heard, is quite difficult. I've only ever worked with unrelated individuals. You could either perform 2 for the mean of the $P$-values, or perhaps even the proportion declared significant, and as you say permute. I think that would give a pretty robust answer, but that's just me. Hope someone else chimes in.